# GAE flex vm (golang) instance regularly logging "connect: network is unreachable"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have a google app engine (gae) flexible env (golang) app that is frequently seeing "connect: network is unreachable" error message for http get requests.. We use the external network for fetching external various images..

err msg: `dial tcp [2a03:2880:f00b:8:face:b00c:0:1]:443: connect: network is unreachable`

Anybody from the google cloud team here that can assist us on this? Will provide additional details if necessary.. We are a paid google cloud customer, but dont have premium support.

This is somewhat critical, as we are experiencing this on our prod hosts (us/west).

Comment: Can you provide more info on where you're seeing this error message? Are you failing to make connection to certain IPs? Have you tried SSHing into the instance (App Engine => Instances on Cloud Console) and tracing the route to that IP?

Comment: @RodrigodeCastro This error has mysterioysly stopped. Will open question again with more details if it surfaces again! Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has mysteriously disappeared from our logs for now...